# ajax deleting button deletes from database but i must reload the page to see the changes?

Tags: ajax

**first page**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){         
    $(".delete_buttom").click(function(){  
    var x = $(this).attr('id');  
    click_delete(x);  
    });  

    function click_delete(x){  
    var commentId = x;  
    $.post("ajax_comments3.php",  
   {  
        task : "this is the task",  
        commentId : commentId  
    }  
    ).success(  
        function(data){  
             $('.li_style').remove(data);  
        }
    ).error(function(){  
       alert("404 not found");  
        });  
}  
</script>
```

**html code**

```
<ul class="ul_style">                  
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($excute_select)){  

if(!empty($row['commet_text'])) {  ?>  

    <li class="li_style" >  

   <img src="profile.jpg" class="user_img_src" />  

   <h5 class="username"><?php echo "mohamed daif" ;?></h5>  

   <div class="delete_buttom" id="<?php echo $row['comment_id'] ; ?>">X</div>  

   <div class="user_comment"><?php echo $row['commet_text'] ; ?> </div>  

   </li>  

  <?php }  

  }   ?>    

 </ul>
```

### in the html code i used php to get data from database

**second page**

```
<?php  
$host_name = "localhost";  
$database_user = "root";  
$password = "";  
$database_name = "comments";  
if(isset($_POST["task"]) && $_POST["task"] == "this is the task"){  
    $commentId = $_POST["commentId"];  
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host_name,$database_user,$password,$database_name) 
        or die("connection failed");  
   $delete_query = "delete from comment where comment_id = $commentId ";  
   $excute_delete = mysqli_query($connection,$delete_query) or die("delete query error");  
}  
?>
```

it works fine and delete from database but in the browser when i click the delete button it hide all the other comments till i reload the page to see the changes

**if any thing in my question is unclear let me knew guys**

Comment: What part of your code is supposed to update the page, and what is that change supposed to be?

Comment: in the second page it suppose to delete the comment box and it did that but i cannot see the changes till i reload the page by my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an id tag to you list element like

```
<li id="comment_<?php echo $row['comment_id'] ; ?>" class="li_style" >
```

then change your script to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){         
    $(".delete_buttom").click(function(){  
    var x = $(this).attr('id');  
    click_delete(x);  
    });  

    function click_delete(commentId){ 
    $.post("ajax_comments3.php",  
   {  
        task : "this is the task",  
        commentId : commentId  
    }  
    ).success(  
        function(data){  
             $('#comment_' + commentId).remove();  
        }
    ).error(function(){  
       alert("404 not found");  
        });  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: I think removing the element form the DOM is better than hiding it with CSS.

Comment: naw103 thanks thats work fine but could you explain the click_delete function because it's confusion for me

Comment: in the click delete function you are passing in your comment id. Previously you were receiving the variable x as a parameter and declaring a second variable commentId with the same value so I just removed that. You are then making your ajax call and passing the comment id to your server so that it knows which comment to delete. as long as no error happens on your server the success function will execute. Here I was just taking the list element with the correct id and hiding it on the page.

Comment: but i want to delete it not hide it

Comment: then just change .hide() to .remove()